# Improving JavaScript path finding algorithm

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, visual-studio

I'm working on an HTML/JavaScript flowchart designer similar to Visual Studio flowchart designer. One of the most fascinating features of VS flowchart designer, is its intelligent path creation algorithm, I think there should be a powerful path finding algorithm behind the scenes (something like A* for example).

I've implemented a path finding algorithm (a simple version of A*) in my application which tries to find a path between my source and destination nodes. Although it is generating the expected results, but it is really poor in terms of performance and speed, as it takes a long calculation time (in fact the calculation time increases as the path gets longer).

What are your suggestions for improving the performance? Do you know how Visual Studio is finding the path so quickly?

Comment: We can't help you improve your algorithm if you don't share it with us...

Comment: Also, Visual Studio is written in a multi-threaded language that can do things in parallel, while JS is inherently single-threaded. I don't know if the Visual Studio algorithm takes advantage of multiple threads, but if it does you're never going to see that performance in JS.

Comment: You just mentioned a great point! Multithreaded, do you think web-workers can help me improve my performance? my algorithm is a normal A* algorithm.

Comment: I don't know enough about web-workers, sorry :( Maybe you should rephrase your question into how to write an A* search using web-workers?

Comment: Thanks anyway, in fact web-workers are a way to simulate multithreading in JavaScript, although as you had mentioned, JS is inherently a single-threaded system, I think it is the only way of improving the performance and increasing application responsiveness. Do you know how does Visual Studio create its path?

Comment: No clue sorry. I would assume the source code is non-open and held pretty guarded by Microsoft.